# ¿Cómo multiplicar los valores de dos input's de manera dinámicos?

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito multiplicar dos valores "cantidad_req" y "valor_unitreq" y que el resultado me lo arroje en el campo "valor_totreq". Lo que creería es que debo poner un contador dentro de la función, pero sé que debo agregar otras cosas.
He buscado ejemplos en internet, pero la verdad es que no entiendo mucho.

Esta es la función para el input estático:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function multiplicar(){
  m1 = document.getElementById("cantidad_req1").value;
  m2 = document.getElementById("valor_unitreq1").value;
  r = m1*m2;
  document.getElementById("valor_totreq1").value = r;
}
</script>
```

Y éste es el código donde se van agregando más input's:

```
function campoAjax(){
    var xmlhttp=false;
    try {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try {
           xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (E) {
            xmlhttp = false;
        }
    }

    if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}

   $(document).ready(function(){     
        $('#validar').on('click', function(){   

        var a=document.getElementById('ag_cam').value;  
        a++;

        $('#ag_cam').val(a);
        if (a<20)
        {
             $('<tr id="contra'+a+'">\n\
                    <td><input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="a" name="a" value="'+a+'"></td>\n\
                    <td><center><input type="text" style="border-radius: 5px; width: 47px;" type="text" id="itemrequ'+a+'"  name="itemrequ'+a+'"></center></td>\n\
                    <td><select type="text" style="border-radius: 5px; width: 320px; height: 30px;" type="text" id="descrip_req'+a+'" name="descrip_req'+a+'" ></select></td>\n\
                    <td><center><input type="text" style="border-radius: 5px; width: 55px;" type="text" id="cantidad_req'+a+'"  name="cantidad_req'+a+'" ></center></td>\n\
                    <td><center><input type="text" style="border-radius: 5px; width: 55px;" type="text" id="undadmsreq'+a+'"     name="undadmsreq'+a+'" ></center></td>\n\
                    <td><select type="text" style="border-radius: 5px; width: 105px; height: 30px;" type="text" id="obra'+a+'" name="obra'+a+'" ></select></td>\n\
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" type="text" id="valor_unitreq'+a+'" size="4" name="valor_unitreq'+a+'" ></td>\n\
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" type="text" id="valor_totreq'+a+'" size="4" name="valor_totreq'+a+'" ></td>\n\
                    <td><input type="button" id="eliminar" class="eliminar" value="'+a+'"></td></tr>alert(a)').appendTo("#requi" ); 


                $("input.eliminar").click(function(){       
                    var mate=$(this).attr("value");
                    $("#contra"+mate).remove();
                    $('#ag_cam').val(a);
                });
                a--;
        }
         lis_obra();
         lis_d();





    });
```

¿La función debería meterla dentro de campoAjax?

Comment: En donde llamas a la funcion multiplicar()?

Comment: Disculpa, ese código lo hiciste tu solo, o lo copiaste de algún lugar, no comprendo que tiene que ver multiplicar los valores de dos `input`, con lo demás.

Comment: La llamo en la vista, pero no vi necesario poner parte de ese código, porque en el estático funciona. Sólo necesitaba un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo de manera dinámica. @alanfcm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas muy cerca de lo que quieres, simplemente tienes que pasar el id de la fila a tu funcion multiplicar() asi:

```js
function multiplicar(id){
    m1 = document.getElementById("cantidad_req" + id).value;
    m2 = document.getElementById("valor_unitreq" + id).value;
    r = m1*m2;
    document.getElementById("valor_totreq" + id).value = r;
}

$(document).ready(function(){               

        var a=10;  
        a++;

        $('#ag_cam').val(a);
        if (a<20)
        {
             $('<tr id="contra'+a+'">\n\
                    <td><input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="a" name="a" value="'+a+'"></td>\n\
                    <td><center><input type="text" style="border-radius: 5px; width: 47px;" type="text" id="itemrequ'+a+'"  name="itemrequ'+a+'"></center></td>\n\
                    <td><select type="text" style="border-radius: 5px; width: 320px; height: 30px;" type="text" id="descrip_req'+a+'" name="descrip_req'+a+'" ></select></td>\n\
                    <td><center><input type="text" style="border-radius: 5px; width: 55px;" type="text" id="cantidad_req'+a+'"  name="cantidad_req'+a+'" ></center></td>\n\
                    <td><center><input type="text" style="border-radius: 5px; width: 55px;" type="text" id="undadmsreq'+a+'"     name="undadmsreq'+a+'" ></center></td>\n\
                    <td><select type="text" style="border-radius: 5px; width: 105px; height: 30px;" type="text" id="obra'+a+'" name="obra'+a+'" ></select></td>\n\
                    <td><input type="text" onblur="multiplicar('+a+')"class="form-control" type="text" id="valor_unitreq'+a+'" size="4" name="valor_unitreq'+a+'" ></td>\n\
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" type="text" id="valor_totreq'+a+'" size="4" name="valor_totreq'+a+'" ></td>\n\
                    <td><input type="button" id="eliminar" class="eliminar" value="'+a+'"></td></tr>alert(a)').appendTo("#requi" ); 

                $("input.eliminar").click(function(){       
                    var mate=$(this).attr("value");
                    $("#contra"+mate).remove();
                    $('#ag_cam').val(a);
                });
                a--;
        }
         lis_obra();
         lis_d();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="requi"></table>
```

Comment: podrías usar el editor del sitio, de paso queda un ejemplo funcional?

Comment: No, me genera la respuesta en 0

Comment: A que te refieres?

Comment: <td><input type="text" class="form-control" type="text" id="valor_unitreq'+a+'"  size="4"  name="valor_unitreq'+a+'" onChange='multiplicar();' ></td>\n\

Comment: function multiplicar(){
                     m1 = document.getElementById("cantidad_req" + a).value;
                     m2 = document.getElementById("valor_unitreq" + a).value;
                     r = m1*m2;
                    document.getElementById("valor_totreq" + a).value = r;
                        }

Comment: Lo hice así, porque yo ya tengo un contador, entonces no veo por qué darle otro, pero hay un error en la función porque no me deja agregar celdas.

Comment: En primer lugar no le estas pasando el id a la funcion, y en segundo esta funcion no tiene nada que ver con agregar celdas.

Comment: Yo sé que no tiene nada que ver con agg celdas, pero lo que quiero decir es que cuando agrego el "onChange" a el input, no me deja agglas, quiere decir que algo esta mal. 
Lo que trato de entender es para qué el id si ya tengo un contador, yo necesito es que vaya sumando a medida que agg celdas.

Comment: En lugar de usar comillas simples tienes que usar comillas dobles como en mi respuesta.  Si no pasas el id, como quieres que la funcion substituya la variable "a" que es local a esa funcion?

Comment: Ya lo hice así, aun así no me sale el resultado en el campo de valor total. Ya reemplacé todo como tú dices

Comment: Ya edite la respuesta

Comment: Gracias, me funcionó. Te agradezco.

Comment: Al fin, me alegro, no te olvides de marcar la respuesta como correcta

Comment: Jajajaja, creo que me adelanté un poco, ahora me genera error con la estática, me dice esto "Cannot read property 'value' of null"

Comment: Ya lo arreglé!!! Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Veo que utilizas JQuery a medias, si ya lo incluiste en el proyecto es mejor usarlo a lo largo de todo el código.

Te agrego un ejemplo de como utilizando JQuery se pueden generar los renglones extra y realizar las operaciones necesarias para obtener los totales conforme se vayan llenando los campos, podrás adaptarlo para que se acople a tu trabajo.

```js
function creaRenglon() {
  var cont = $(".material").length;
  var html = "<tr id = 'material"+(cont+1)+"' class = 'material'>"+
    "<td><input type = 'text' class = 'cantidad_req' onkeyup='obtTotalMat("+(cont+1)+")'></td>"+
    "<td><input type = 'text' class = 'valor_unitreq' onkeyup='obtTotalMat("+(cont+1)+")'></td>"+
    "<td><input type = 'text' class = 'valor_totreq' onchange='calcTotal()'></td>"+
   "</tr>";
  $("#tablaReq tbody").append(html);
}

function obtTotalMat(index){
 var tot = $("#material"+index+" .cantidad_req").val() * $("#material"+index+" .valor_unitreq").val();
 $("#material"+index+" .valor_totreq").val(tot);
 
 calcTotal();
}

function calcTotal() {
  var tot = 0;
  $(".material .valor_totreq").each(function () {
    tot+=Number($(this).val());
  });
  $("#granTotal").val(tot);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id ="tablaReq">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Cantidad</th>
  <th>Precio unitario</th>
  <th>Total</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp</td>
  <td>Gran total:</td>
  <td>
    <input id= "granTotal">
  </td>
<tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
<a href="#" onclick ="creaRenglon()">Agregar material</a>
```